# Nodejs Sqllite3 not flushing to disk

Tags: node.js, sqlite, node-sqlite3

I'm having problem with sqlite3 not flush to disk. The code I'm using is below. My total filelist are over 470k and the program tends to use several gigabytes of memory. while the program is running test.db is 0 bytes and no journal is used. It only starts to write to disk when  `db.close()` is running.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
var db = new sqlite3.Database('test.db');

db.serialize(function () {
    db.run("BEGIN;");
    db.run("CREATE TABLE if not exists Files (name TEXT);");
    db.run("COMMIT;");
    var files = fs.readdirSync("./files/");
    console.log("File list completed: " + files.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        db.run("INSERT INTO Files VALUES (?);",files[i]);
    }
});
db.close();
```

I have have tried to remove `db.run("BEGIN;");` and  `db.run("COMMIT;");` but it does not help.

**Bug?**

I'm reporting this as a bug on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm think that there is a problem with `transaction` and `db.serialize`.
`db.serialize` is uncontrolled code. I don't know when it's useful. 
Try control flow like below

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3'); 
var async = require('async');

var db = new sqlite3.Database('test.db');

async.series ([
        function(cb) { 
            db.run('CREATE TABLE if not exists Files (name TEXT)', cb);
        },

        function(cb) { 
            db.run('begin transaction', cb); 
        },

        function(cb) {
            var files = fs.readdirSync("./files/");
            async.each(
                files, 
                function(file, cb) { db.run('INSERT INTO Files VALUES (?)', file, cb); }, 
                cb  
            );
        },

        function(cb) {
            db.run('commit transaction', cb);
        }
    ],
    function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            db.run('rollback transaction'); // can fail if error occurs on create table
        }
        db.close();
    }
)
```

---

If you don't need `insert all rows or nothing` that you can try next code

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3'); 
var async = require('async');

var db = new sqlite3.Database('test.db');

db.run('CREATE TABLE if not exists Files (name TEXT)', function (err) {
    if (err)
        return console.log(err);

    var files = fs.readdirSync("./files/");
    async.eachSeries(
        files, 
        function(file, cb) { db.run('INSERT INTO Files VALUES (?)', file, cb); }, 
        function(err) {
            console.log((err) ? err : 'Done');
            db.close();
        }  
    );
});
```

Comment: I have tried the code and for me it just gobbles memory.

Comment: You can try `commit` after each insert.

Comment: I have tried that`
    var fs = require('fs');
    var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
    var db = new sqlite3.Database('test.db');
    var files = fs.readdirSync("./files/");
    console.log("File list completed: " + files.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        db.run("begin;");
        db.run("INSERT INTO Files VALUES (?);", files[i]);
        db.run("commit;");
        console.log(files[i]);
    }
db.close();´ with the same result

Comment: This is incorrect attempt because you mix sync and async code.

Comment: Where is the mix? I only see sync code. Or are you referring to the db.run that is running parallel?

Comment: `db.run` is async func, but you use it as sync. So `db.run` calls execute parallel.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks!